# How to improve cats and dogs classification using CNN with pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I tried to follow the architecture of CNN in this paper, ImageNet Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks (https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf). In this paper, they tried to classify 1000 classes, whereas I am just trying to classify 2 classes.

But, my test accuracy got stuck at 50%, and the model is not learning.

I am training with 23K images of cats and dogs, and test with 2500 images.

This is URL to my notebook https://github.com/jinglescode/workspace/blob/master/my-journey-computer-vision/codes/Cats_and_Dogs.ipynb

Could anyone advise what's wrong? What have I missed out? Willing to learn.

Comment: normalisation will help a lot to get better result. I think you should also think again about you'r data augmentation: i'm not sure doing horizontal flip or 30° rotation helps

Comment: @akhetos thanks for your input, Shai and you mentioned about normalisation, and I did it. see my updated notebook
[https://github.com/jinglescode/workspace/blob/master/my-journey-computer-vision/codes/Cats_and_Dogs.ipynb]. i also have removed the augmentation to make things simpler.

any more ideas?

Comment: i don't know pytorch syntax and no time to understand it, but the first thing is to check at you'r model shape. In keras this can be done with `model.summary()`. If you still have 50% accuracy after normalisation,main  problem is probably coming from you'r model architecture not learning rate

Answer (score 0):

## [Normalize your data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57252898/1714410)!!

For image data, you can use the [recommended `transform`](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py#L197-L198) to your train and test datasets

```py
normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomRotation(30),
                                       transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
                                       transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                                       normalize]) 

test_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(255),
                                      transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                                      transforms.ToTensor(),
                                      normalize])
```

---

Additional comments:

1. If you want to "peek" into a dataloader, instantiating `next(iter(dataloader))` is [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53280967/1714410). Instead, you can access the dataset stored inside the dataloader and use its `__getitem__`:

   ```
    images, labels = dataloader.dataset[0]
   ```
2. If your training is "stuck", the usual first reaction is to change the learning rate

Comment: thanks @Shai, I have normalised the data like you said,
and used `for images, labels in trainloader` to iterate through dataset. 
updated notebook [https://github.com/jinglescode/workspace/blob/master/my-journey-computer-vision/codes/Cats_and_Dogs.ipynb]

in the paper, they mentioned that the learning rate was divided by 10 when the validation did not improve. whereas I'm using Adam (starting from 0.01). any thoughts about this?